# React router: Location did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can someone help me with following issue:

```
<Route path="/" component={ App } >
    <Route path="posts/(:id)" component={ PostsIndex } />
    <Route path="admin" component={ Admin } />
</Route>
```

When I add dynamic routing **(:id)**, I get an error: [react-router] Location "/posts" did not match any routes.

I delete the (:id) and everything just works fine.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Try replacing from (:id) to :id and tell me if that worked.

Comment: not :id nor (:id)

Answer (score 2):

```
<Route path="/" component={ App } >
    <Route path="posts" component={ PostsIndex }>
         <Route path="posts/:id" component={ PostsIndex } />
    </Route>
    <Route path="admin" component={ Admin } />
</Route>
```

Nested routes should help in this case.

Comment: That option gives me another error:
GET http://localhost:8080/posts/app.59759542b05016899723.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then you referenced your app.js in your HTML incorrectly. Instead of `<script src="app.js">` try `<script src="/app.js">`.